# For a given n find the maximum number k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the the maximum number **k** for a given **n**, such that **n** can be represented as the sum of **k** different natural terms.

Example:

MaxNumberOfTerms(4) = 2, because 1+3=4  **or**

MaxNumberOfTerms(6) = 3, because 1+2+3=6

Comment: Hint: for $n$ of the form $k(k+1)/2$ (triangular number), the maximum is $k$.

Comment: I can't understand why the question has been flagged as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

When $n=\dfrac{k(k+1)}2$, the maximum is $k$.

When $\dfrac{(k-1)k}2<n<\dfrac{k(k+1)}2$ you can't achieve better than $k-1$ (as this would violate the upper bound), but you can achieve it by using all integers from $1$ to $k-2$ and the remainder $n-\dfrac{(k-2)(k-1)}2>k-1$.

---

To summarize,

$$k=\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\rfloor.$$